# Maximum Amplitude when silence - Wave file processing

Tags: c#, wav, audio-processing

I created a wav parser. I read the sample information out of the data chunk like this:

```
while (offset < size)
{
    var value = 0;
    switch (bits_channel)
    {
        case 8:
            value = data.SubArray(offset, 1)[0];
            break;

        case 16:
            value = BitConverter.ToInt16(data.SubArray(offset, 2), 0x0);
            break;

        default:
            value = BitConverter.ToInt32(data.SubArray(offset, bits_channel / 8), 0x0);
            break;
    }

    samples[channel].Add(value);
    //Tools.Log("Read value: " + samples[channel].Last() + ", " + bits_channel);

    offset += bits_channel;
    channel = (channel + 1) % numchannels;
}
```

where SubArray is a function, which creates (obviously) a subarray with startindex and length, and offset is the current offset in bits in the data.

My test file looks like this in audacity:
[image]

but like this when I read it into my parser:
[image]

So basically you see, where the great amplitude is on the timeline, but where it is almost completely silent in audacity, it appears as maximul amplitude in my program. What could potentially be the issue?

Comment: What is samples and channel?

Comment: samples is a `List<List<int>>`, which stores the sample information like `samples[channel][samplenum]` and channels is an integer which gets increased everytime I read a sample value modulo the number of channels

Comment: What bits_channel is used in your example? It's constant throughout a whole .wav file, isn't it?

Comment: Its the bits per channel and it is constant, in a 16-bit wave it is 16 all the time

Comment: Your example is 16? Do you have one in 8 bits? Maybe your conversion is off...

Comment: Also, which programming language are you using?

Comment: I got a song which is in 8 bit but I recorded this test file to better see whats going on. Unfortunately audacity only seems to support 16 bit wav files. C#

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126859/discussion-between-mordechays-and-tom-doodler).

Comment: Any progress? Did you check what happens with an 8 bit test file?